# How to set a particular column value to a variable based on condition from a select expression that return multiple records in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This is the situation. I have an image table contains image_id, image_location, and image_description fields.

I need to write an SQL to select 3 random images (randomize the image_id) also each image has an **Image_Counter** that is also randomized (1 to 10) so each image will appear (in the front end) **Image_Counter** number of times

```
SELECT i.Image_Location, FLOOR(RAND()*10)+1 AS Image_Counter, false AS Use_Button 
FROM images i 
WHERE i.Image_ID IN (rand2,rand3,rand4) 
ORDER BY i.Image_ID;
```

`rand2,rand3,rand4` are random numbers generated in an earlier statement to randomize image by id.

But I need to know whatever random number generated for `Image_Counter` when `Image_ID=rand2` and set it to a variable because when `Image_ID=rand2`  it is the picture displayed as a question in front end and I need the `Image_Counter` for that image to be stored as an answer later.

This is what happens when I execute it

- Image_Location_____Image_Counter_______Use_Button
- blackhorse01.jpg__________9________________0
- pinkpurse01.jpg___________6________________0
- giraffe01.jpg______________4________________0

In this case, pinkpurse01.jpg is the image with Image_ID=rand2 so need to store 6 to a variable to use it later.

How to do it?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this way and it worked

```
    SET randnumberofpic= FLOOR(RAND()*10)+1;
    
    SELECT i.Image_Location, CASE  i.Image_ID
                               WHEN rand2 THEN 
                                randnumberofpic
                               ELSE FLOOR(RAND()*10)+1  
                             END Image_Counter, 
    false AS Use_Button 
    FROM images i WHERE i.Image_ID IN (rand2,rand3,rand4) ORDER BY
    i.Image_ID;
    
    SELECT randnumberofpic AS Answer;
```